# Error An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

The code below is producing this error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at line 26

```
<form:form  method="post" action="/login" commandName="Login" >
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>UserName</p>
            <form:input path="username"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>Password</p>
            <form:input type="password" path="userpassword"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
                <a href="/registration">Sign Up</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp at line 26

Comment: You are not closing the input tag.

Comment: Post the whole html code please.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your run time environment. if you are using eclipse then you need to follow below images.
[image]
[image]

I think it will work for you.